strict inequality for Fatou's lemma
It is not the well-known form of Fatou's lemma. It is shown as below:
let $g\ge 0$ be continuous. If $X_n$ weakly converge to $X$ then
$$\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow \infty} Eg(X_n)\ge Eg(X)$$
I'd like to find a example that makes this left strictly smaller than the right.
Thank you.

You are asking in the wrong forum.

"It is not the well-known form of Fatou's lemma." It actually follows immediately from (say) very simple Theorems 2.7 and 3.4 in Billingsley's book.
The inequality in question will be strict if e.g. $g(x)=\max(0,x)$ for real $x$, $X=0$, and $X_n=n\,1(U<1/n)$, where $U$ is a random variable uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,1]$. Indeed, then $X_n\to X$ almost surely and hence in probability and hence in distribution,
$Eg(X_n)=EX_n=1$, and $Eg(X)=EX=0$.

Sorry. It is a typo. It is fixed now.

@ZhuozhenJiang : Do you have a further response to my answer?

It is a good example. I get it. Thank you for answering and sharing the book. I will read it after finishing Durret's.
